# I'm having the following error in the console and i been trying to fix it for hours

Tags: flutter, dart, null-safety

[This the is error console is showing. It says it's in Root widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rC1uC.png)

**This is my code**

'''

```
  initState: (_) async {
    Get.put<UserController>(UserController());
  }, 
  builder: (_) {
    if (Get.find<AuthController>().user?.isEmpty == true){
      return HomeScreen();
    } else {
      return Login();
    }
  }
```

'''

**AuthController with firebase, i used Rxn for null safety.**

'''

```
class AuthController extends GetxController {
  FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  Rxn<User> _firebaseUser = Rxn<User>();

  String? get user => _firebaseUser.value?.email;

  @override
  void onInit() {
    _firebaseUser.bindStream(_auth.authStateChanges());
  }
}
```

'''

**UserController**

```
  Rx<UserModel> _userModel = UserModel().obs;

  UserModel? get user => _userModel.value;

  set user(UserModel? value) => this._userModel.value = value!;

  void clear(){
    _userModel.value = UserModel();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're forcing the nullable user into non-null using the `!`:

```dart
if (Get.find<AuthController>().user!.isEmpty){
```

Instead, null check it with `?`

```dart
if (Get.find<AuthController>().user?.isEmpty == true){
```

You almost never want to force a nullable using `!` unless you've already null checked it earlier in your code.

Comment: thank you for the help Nico, i tried that before I posted this question and it was giving me this error 
**A nullable expression can't be used as a condition.
Try checking that the value isn't 'null' before using it as a condition.dartunchecked_use_of_nullable_value**

Comment: Oh right, You'll need to explicitly check against the boolean value you want to test against if it's nullable. I've updated the answer.

Comment: please help, it's still giving me the same error in the photo :(

Comment: `class AuthController extends GetxController {
  FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  Rxn<User> _firebaseUser = Rxn<User>();

  String? get user => _firebaseUser.value?.email;

  @override
  void onInit() {
    _firebaseUser.bindStream(_auth.authStateChanges());
  }
}`

This is my AuthController, if it helps

Comment: please update your question and put it in a code block. can you also include your UserController?

Comment: it's updated, i'm so sorry for the late response, was busy with uni assignments